# Program that guesses your number using bitwise operations

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11, bitwise, number-guessing-game

I got the idea for this program from [this site](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/Cards.shtml).

**functions.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

namespace my
{
    int getOneOrZero()
  {
    return (rand() >> 14);   // >> the bitwise operator
  }

// getArray leaves the numbers ( 0-99 ) that have in their bit position        represented by bigFlag the num ( 0 or 1 )

void printNums(int8_t bitFlag, int num)    // num is from getOneOrZero() so it's 1 or 0;
{
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; ++counter)  // there are quite a few implicit conversions to one byte integers
        {
            if ( (counter & bitFlag) != num*bitFlag )
                std::cout << std::setw(8) << " ";
            else
                std::cout << std::setw(8) << counter;

            if ( (counter % 9) == 0)
                std::cout << std::endl;
        }
}

char getAnswer()
{
    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "\n Is your number shown above ?\n\n 'y' for yes , 'n' for no , 'r' for reset : ";
        char answer;
        std::cin >> answer;
        std::cin.ignore(32767,'\n');

        if (std::cin.fail())
            std::cin.clear();

        if (answer == 'y' || answer == 'n' || answer == 'r')   // I could use switch but nevermind
            return answer;
    }
}

void turnsPassed(int turns)
{
    std::cout << "\n This is turn " << turns << "\n\n";
}

int swapZeroOrOne(int num)
{
    switch (num)
    {
    case 0 :
        return 1;
    case 1 :
        return 0;
    default:
        std::cout << "\nSwapZeroOrOne ERROR !\n";
        break;
    }
}

int getUpdateForGuessNum(int8_t flag, int num, char answer)
{
    switch (answer)
    {
    case 'n' :
        { int newNum = swapZeroOrOne(num);
          return newNum*flag;
        }
    case 'y' :
        return num*flag;
    case 'r' :
        break;
    default  :
        std::cout << "\n ERROR ! In getUpdateForGuessNum\n";
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include "functions.hpp"
#include "constants.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>      // for system() commands >.<
int main()
{
srand( static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));

Reset :      // goto !
system("cls");

int guessNum = 0;

// guessing loop !

for (int counter = 0; counter < 7; ++counter)
{
    if (counter == 0)
        std::cout << "\n Think of a number between 0 to 99\n";

    my::turnsPassed(counter + 1);  // +1 cause counter starts from 0

    int num {my::getOneOrZero()};  // this gives a randomness to the numbers shown each time you run the programm

    my::printNums(myVar::bitFlag[counter],num);

    char answer { my::getAnswer() };

    if (answer == 'r')
        goto Reset;

    guessNum |= my::getUpdateForGuessNum(myVar::bitFlag[counter],num,answer);

    system("cls");
}

std::cout << "\n Your number is \n";
std::cout << "\n" << std::setfill('-')  << std::setw(81) << "\n";
std::cout << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(41) << guessNum << "\n";
std::cout << "\n" << std::setfill('-')  << std::setw(81) << "\n";

system("pause");  // I should fix this

return 0;
}
```

**functions.hpp:**

```
#pragma once

namespace my
{
    int getOneOrZero();
    void printNums(int8_t,int);
    char getAnswer();
    void turnsPassed(int);
    int getUpdateForGuessNum(int8_t,int,char);
    int swapZeroOrOne(int);

}
```

**constants.hpp:**

```
#pragma once

namespace myVar
{
    const int8_t bitFlag[] {0x1, 0x2, 0x4, 0x8, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80};
}
```

Please suggest ways to improve this program. Explain the suggestions you make because I need to know why I should change something.

Comment: You can get my exe from my dropbox here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/c23oecv5g3sgnf0/Number%20guessing%20in%207%20turns%20%21.exe?dl=0

Comment: Nobody is going to run a random exe. Everybody can read and compile your source if they need.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Understand type implications

The code includes a `bitFlag` array that is declared as `const int8_t` but then contains a value that is `0x80`.  The problem with that is that when the compiler encounters the constant `0x80`, it converts it into an `int` by default, and so that would be the value 128.  However, 128 is not representable in an `int8_t`.  That bit pattern is actually -128 as an `int8_t`, so I'd recommend either using a different type (such as `uint8_t`) for the variable or writing `-0x80` for the constant which is correct, but a little strange looking.

### Know the standard types

This function is in the current code:

```
int getOneOrZero()
{
    return (rand() >> 14);   // >> the bitwise operator
}
```

There are two problems with this.  The first is that it apparently assumes that an `int` is 16 bits.  However, on my machine, an int is 64 bits.  In general, you can't assume that the size of an `int` is a fixed size.  The standard only says (implicitly from the required range) that it must be 16 bits, but it may be larger.  The second problem is addressed in the next point.

### Consider using a better random number generator

Because you are using a compiler that supports at least C++11, consider using a better random number generator.  In particular, instead of `rand`, you might want to look at [`std::bernoulli_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/bernoulli_distribution) and friends in the `<random>` header.

Here's one way to rewrite it:

```
int getOneOrZero()
{
    static std::mt19937 gen{std::random_device{}()};
    static std::bernoulli_distribution bd;
    return bd(gen);   
}
```

### Ensure every control path returns a proper value

The `swapZeroOrOne` routine returns `1` or `0` under some set of conditions but then doesn't return anything at all otherwise (although it prints an error essage).  This is an error because *all* control paths should return a value.  Since it's only used once, and because it can be trivially rewritten, I'd probably replace this:

```
case 'n' :
    { int newNum = swapZeroOrOne(num);
      return newNum*flag;
    }
```

with this:

```
    return (1-num)*flag;
```

### Avoid using `goto`

Having a `goto` statement in modern C++ is usually a sign of bad design.  Better would be to eliminate them entirely -- it makes the code easier to follow and less error-prone.  In this code, it's probable that you could use a loop instead:

```
for (bool playing=true; playing;  )
    // code to play the game
    // ask user if they want to play again
    playing = answer == 'r'; 
}
```

### Don't use `system("cls")`

There are two reasons not to use `system("cls")` or `system("pause")`.  The first is that it is not portable to other operating systems which you may or may not care about now.  The second is that it's a security hole, which you absolutely **must** care about.  Specifically, if some program is defined and named `cls` or `pause`, your program will execute that program instead of what you intend, and that other program could be anything.  First, isolate these into a seperate functions `cls()` and `pause()` and then modify your code to call those functions instead of `system`.  Then rewrite the contents of those functions to do what you want using C++.  For example, if your terminal supports [ANSI Escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), you could use this:

```
void cls()
{
    std::cout << "\x1b[2J";
}
```

### Think of the user

If the user were to get an error message that said:

> ERROR ! In getUpdateForGuessNum

What use is that unless they also happen to be the author of the code?  Instead, for errors that are an indication of a program flaw, I'd use `assert` or for things that are unusual but still should be accomodated by the program, use an `exception`.

### Use objects

You have a `guessNum` and `counter` to support the game and then separate functions `printNums` and `getAnswer`, etc. that operate on `guessNum`. With only a slight syntax change, you would have a real object instead of C-style code written in C++.  You could declare a `GuessNum` object and then `printNums`, `getAnswer`, etc. could all be member functions.

### Don't use std::endl unless you really need to flush the stream

The difference between `std::endl` and `'\n'` is that `std::endl` actually flushes the stream. This can be a costly operation in terms of processing time, so it's best to get in the habit of only using it when flushing the stream is actually required. It's not for this code.

### Omit `return 0`

When a C or C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no need to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.

**Note:** when I make this suggestion, it's almost invariably followed by one of two kinds of comments:  "I didn't know that." or "That's bad advice!"  My rationale is that it's safe and useful to rely on compiler behavior explicitly supported by the standard.  For C, since C99; see ISO/IEC 9899:1999 section 5.1.2.2.3:

> [...] a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument; reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0.

For C++, since the first standard in 1998; see ISO/IEC 14882:1998 section 3.6.1:

> If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;

All versions of both standards since then (C99 and C++98) have maintained the same idea.  We rely on automatically generated member functions in C++, and few people write explicit `return;` statements at the end of a `void` function.  Reasons against omitting seem to boil down to ["it looks weird"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581993/what-the-reasons-for-against-returning-0-from-main-in-iso-c/2582015#2582015).  If, like me, you're curious about the rationale for the change to the C standard [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394171/what-was-the-rationale-for-making-return-0-at-the-end-of-main-optional).  Also note that in the early 1990s this was considered "sloppy practice" because it was undefined behavior (although widely supported) at the time.

So I advocate omitting it; others disagree (often vehemently!)  In any case, if you encounter code that omits it, you'll know that it's explicitly supported by the standard and you'll know what it means.

Comment: I've changed `int getOneOrZero()
{
    return (rand() >> 14);   // >> the bitwise operator
}` with `int getOneOrZero()
    {
        return (rand() >> (sizeof(int)*8 - 2) );   // >> the bitwise operator
    }`

Comment: I've changed `return (rand() >> 14);` with `return (rand() >> (sizeof(int)*8 - 2) );`

As for the return I want it from any iteration to just reset ( as the name implies ) . Isn't a goto good enough ? :/

I've learned quite a few things from your post thanks a lot It is very useful :D I will make sure to do once I learn how to from the site I'm learning the Object Oriented way :D 
 **I coudn't edit the above post **

Comment: ** Another edit** As for the reset not As for the return

Comment: The first paragraph gets close, but stops just short of stating it directly: anything you're manipulating or otherwise representing as a bit field should always use *unsigned* types.

Comment: 64-bit integers? what kind of machine would that be?

Answer (score 6):

Some more besides [@Edward's brilliant points](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/151154/52802):

### Do not refactor simple oneliners into functions unnecessarily

```
void turnsPassed(int turns)
{
    std::cout << "\n This is turn " << turns << "\n\n";
}
```

This just obfuscates the output statement for a reader and doesn't add any value over writing that `std::cout` directly in the context (especially since it's called only at one place).

### Do not introduce unnecessary namespaces

Namespaces should be used to group logically and semantically related code together.

There's not much value of separating

```
namespace myVar
{
    const int8_t bitFlag[] {0x1, 0x2, 0x4, 0x8, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80};
}
```

into it's own namespace `myVar`, or even have that declared in a separate header file.

<sub>Also the type should be `uint8_t`, since `0x80` would yield a negative value otherwise.</sub>

It should appear in the same namespace and along with the functions that make use of this array.

In fact it would be better (as mentioned) in the other answer to place everything in a class:

```
class NumberGuessingGame
{
public:
    int getOneOrZero();
    void printNums(int8_t,int);
    char getAnswer();
    void turnsPassed(int);
    int getUpdateForGuessNum(int8_t,int,char);
    int swapZeroOrOne(int);

private:
    const uint8_t bitFlag[] {0x1, 0x2, 0x4, 0x8, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80};
}
```

Also take care to give namespaces or classes resonable and helpful naming for a future reader of your code. `my` and `myVar` do not have any value regarding that.

### Do not use `std::cin.ignore()` unnecessarily

```
std::cin.ignore(32767,'\n');
```

This statement is probably meant to catch up cases when the user made an input of multiple characters in a single line.

First problem is the magic number `32767`, using something like `std::limits<size_t>::max` would be more portable and better to read again.

Also you wouldn't need that whole stuff if you use a `std::string` and `std::getline()` to realize that function. You could rewrite that whole function much simpler then:

```
char getAnswer()
{
    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "\n Is your number shown above ?\n\n 'y' for yes , 'n' for no , 'r' for reset : ";
        std::string answer;
        std::getline(std::cin,answer);

        if (answer[0] == 'y' || answer[0] == 'n' || answer[0] == 'r')
            return answer[0];
        else
            std::cout << "Please enter one of 'y', 'n' or 'r';
    }
}
```

Checking for `fail()` is not needed since there's only char or string input expected anyways.

Comment: Just a small note. I'd suggest renaming your 1st point to a more general advice, like the rest of points e.g. "Do not refactor (one-liners) unnecessarily". It's very easy to falsify and debate this point as it currently stands. 1st Technically, all c++ code can be written in one line. 2nd It's often a good idea to wrap some tricky one-liners in a syntactically meaningful name. I think this overshadows otherwise a very nice answer, creating an unpleasant 1st impression. I think it would be nice to have the 1st punchline not so easily abusable. Cheers.